# Data source for the relative frequency of different kinds of expiration date by retailers? (use by, sell by, best by)

Tags: reference-request, data-request, agriculture, food

I'm not sure if this is the correct Stackexchange site for this question, but I am interested in the economic and environmental effects of food waste reduction. A common policy proposal to reduce food waste is to standardize expiration dates of food so that consumers do not mistakenly discard food before it has spoiled. However it's not easy to assess the effectiveness of the policy without knowing the baseline frequencies of the different types of expiration date (use by, best if used by, sell by, etc.) Is anyone aware of a study or survey that has tried to quantify how often retailers and/or manufacturers use each different type of expiration date label? It would be great to have data for individual food types as well if that exists. This question refers to the USA but I would be interested in data from any country.